# pause VBA and attach file in email for select case

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to pause a `vba` until the user saves an excel attachment (xlsx)? In the VB below the user is prompted upon opening the workbook with a selection, if that selection is yes then another message box appears asking them to fill out a form and save. I am trying to pause the VB until save is clicked. However, I am getting many compile errors currently. That attachment file also needs to be an attachment in the email but only for that case selection. That line is in bold in the code, but as of now there is no attachment. Also,
I get `ActiveX component can't create object` with the `Set MyDoc = Documents.Add` selected. Thank you :).

**VB**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim WS As Worksheet, Rng As Range, c As Range
Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
Dim Msg As String, Addr As String, FName As String, i As Long
Dim obj As Object
Dim MyDoc As Document
Dim MyFileCopy As String
Dim intAnswer As Integer

'define path
  MyFileCopy = "L:\NGS\HLA LAB\total quality management\QC & QA\DOSE reports\DOSE reporting form Attachment.xlsx"

'open sheet
  Sheets("Email").Activate
  intAnswer = MsgBox("Are there any issues to report", vbYesNoCancel)
  Select Case intAnswer
  Case vbYes
  Range("D2").Value = "x"
  MsgBox ("Please select an issue and save"), vbExclamation

 'create a separate sheet2 to mail out and pause VB
   Sheets(2).Copy
   Set wkb = ActiveWorkbook
   With wkb
  **Set MyDoc = Documents.Add
   MyDoc.SaveAs "MyFileCopy.xlsx"
   DoEvents
   Do
   Loop Until MyDoc.Saved
   .Close True
  End With

Case vbCancel
Application.SendKeys "%{F11}", True

Case Else
Range("C2").Value = "x"
End Select

'create connection, check condition, send email
 Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Email")
 With WS
 Set Rng = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
 End With

 For Each c In Rng

Msg = "For " & WS.Cells(2, 2) & Chr(14) & Chr(14)
For i = 3 To 4
If LCase(WS.Cells(2, i)) = "x" Then
Msg = Msg & "   -" & WS.Cells(1, i) & Chr(14)
End If
Next

Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutMail
    .To = c
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Daily Operational Safety Briefing"
    .Body = Msg
    **If Range("D2").Value & Chr(14) = "x" Then .Attachments.Add MyFileCopy, 1**
    .Send
End With
Next c

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

'confirm message sent, clear sheet, and delete copy
 MsgBox "The data has been emailed sucessfully.", vbInformation
 Range("C2:D2").ClearContents
 Kill MyFileCopy


'Exit and do not save
 Application.Quit
 ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the "Form" is actually `Sheet2` and they have to fill something out on it or something like that.

Your best bet is to create a new UserForm and set the property "ShowModal" to False. In that form add a text box with "Please select an issue and save", then you can have a button on the form called "Save" that will have the remainder of your code attached to it.

The workflow then will be:

1. Ask the user "Are there any issues to report"
2. If vbYes then show the user form.
3. When the user is done doing whatever they do, they click "Save" on the form which is still up
4. The rest of your code executes.

Optionally you could use the `Workbook_BeforeSave()` event (Go to the ThisWorkbook in your VBE and at the top of the editor choose "Workbook" form the first drop down and "BeforeSave" in the second) and put the remainder of your code in there. Then the workflow would be:

1. Ask the user "Are there any issues to report"
2. If vbYes then show the message "Please select an issue and save"
3. The user dismisses the message box and does their update
4. The user clicks "Save"
5. The workbook_BeforeSave() event triggers and executes the rest of the code.

You could also make a combination of those and have that "Please select an issue and save" message box be a ShowModal=False userform that just stays up and active while they do their thing and "Save" as they normally would.